# Finding the capacity of a Signal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, signal-processing

I've labelled the image with my questions. Using the Claude Shannon expression we have to find the capacity of this signal.

[image: Capacity Question]

Comment: Come on [this math question was moved to dsp.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36527/relationship-between-sampled-continuous-and-discrete-time-signals) but you upvote thisone ?

Comment: "capacity of signal" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm of a **number** is the exponent to which we have to raise the base to get that **number**. In this case we have:

$$\log_{10}(S/N)=3$$

so the base is $10$, the **number** is $S/N$ and the exponent (Thebes's value of the logarithm) is $3$, hence by definition of logarithm we get:

$$10^3=S/N.$$

For the second issue, we want to evaluate $\log_2(1001)$, but we prefer to change the base; this is possible by means the following formula:

$$\log_ab={\log_cb\over\log_ca}$$

so $\log_21001={\log_{10}1001\over\log_{10}2}$, now you can calculate it by your calculator.